# How to divide URL without Using Collections in Java

Tags: java

Can any one help me How to divide URL without using collections.
Example: I have URL(https://localhost:8080/prodpat/admin/page1)
Have to divide as follows

```
https
localhost
8080
prodapt
admin
page1
```

Comment: Have you read about regex's in java?

Comment: Just use `split("/|:")` (slash OR : )

Comment: @azro That'll give you 2 blanks after the protocol because of `://`

Comment: See the [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class which does the parsing and splitting

Comment: Thanx So much @azro .. it worked

Comment: @marupudivinay you can look my answer down there, and accept the one your prefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
public class SplitURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://localhost:8080/prodpat/admin/page1";
        String[] urlSplitData = url.split("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(urlSplitData));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=0; i<urlSplitData.length; i++) {
            if(urlSplitData[i].trim().length() != 0) {
                sb.append(urlSplitData[i]+"_");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(sb.toString().split("_")));
    }
}
```

**Explanation :**

1. The regex provided to split the string will act like any special character.
2. Now when you split the URL which is having special characters one after the other (like `://`), the split array will be not sufficient to full fill the requirement.
3. So again append the array content (whose length is not zero even after trim not an empty string and not a string with only whitespace) to a `StringBuilder`, with any common seperator like `_`.
4. Finally split the `StringBuilder` after converting to a `String`, using the appended common separator.

That final array will be what you need.

Comment: Don't give answer without comment / explanation / something .. pleas

Comment: So thankful for your explanantion. arun.. exactly what im looking for

Answer (score 3):

**1.** You would be able to find a solution using `split(":|/")`

```
String url = "https://localhost:8080/prodpat/admin/page1";
String[] array = url.split("/|:|://");

String https = array[0];      // https
String localhost = array[1];  // localhost
String port = array[2];       // 8080
String prodapt = array[3];    // prodpat
String admin = array[4];      // admin
String page1 = array[5];      // page1
```

---

**2.** Or use `java.net.URL`, and get back the element you need :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8080/prodpat/admin/page1");
        String https   = url.getProtocol();         // https
        String localhost   = url.getHost();         // localhost
        int port   = url.getPort();                 // 8080
        String[] path   = url.getPath().split("/"); // /prodpat/admin/page1
        String prodapt   = path[1];                 // prodpat
        String admin   = path[2];                   // admin
        String page1   = path[3];                   //page1
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx @azro first solution worked for me... and tried both solutions both works fine

Comment: @marupudivinay thanks. 
But I do not understand why you have accepted the other one ^^ mine is minimalist and just consist in a few few operation  while the one you accepted create dynamic Arrays (twice), stringBuilder, iteration, condition, ... so many heavy things that can be avoided
And he is not giving you the object which holds the element at the end, only a representation ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
    URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8080/prodpat/admin/page1");
    String[] tokens = url.toString().split("://|/|:");
    for (int i =0 ; i < tokens.length ; i++){
        System.out.println( tokens[i] );
    }
```